# Past tense for indicating long distance

Tags: past-tense

Once I read a textbook on Business English.

It says that if you make a long-distance call to a hotel the receptionist might say, "What was your name?"

It also says that **was** is used for showing the long distance between you and her.

But I have never seen such usage since then. Is it a correct usage?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"What was your name?" is simply a more polite way to say "What is your name?". I believe the phrase originated because it is often impolite to ask "What is your name?".

Often this question sounds too direct, and often somebody has already been introduced to you in the past, or has mentioned their name already (for example at the start of a telephone call) but you have forgotten it. In these situations, the use of the past tense suggests that you were told their name and you are sorry you need to ask again.

Another form of this is "What did you say your name was?" which is often used out of habit even when the caller never gave their name before.

Edit: Thanks for the comments and the welcome. To clarify, I personally believe this textbook is incorrect to draw a link between the tense and the distance. Instead, as BobRodes has explains very well, the tense conveys the suggestion that the speaker is asking you to educate them on your already existing needs.

Comment: Also, if she is looking at some kind of log. A call was logged at 8pm, names are listed. She might say *was* because she is looking at events from the past.

Comment: +1 Welcome to ELL! This would be even better if you addressed the confusion (which may be OP's or may be the textbook's) between physical distance and 'social distance' for politeness.

Comment: I cannot imagine what the scenario might be like. Can you plz tell me more about it? @Jolenealaska

Comment: "What was your name **again**?" is how it's typically phrased.

Comment: Also: "Did you want ketchup on your fries?" "Did you want room for cream in your coffee?" "How did you want your eggs?" and so on. The tense conveys the suggestion that I'm asking you to educate me on your understanding of your needs (which you already know) so I can serve them.

Comment: Mr Smurthwaite is new to this site. Perhaps he doesn't know that it is possible for him to edit his answer. You mean the textbook is wrong about the interpretation of **was**; it just goes to show your politeness, right? @StoneyB

Comment: @ZhanlongZheng I don't know the textbook; it may be OP's mistake, caused by the book talking about 'social distance' in the context of a long-distance call. I use a past tense to put my request at a 'distance', make it less demanding, **as if** to say "Gosh, you must have told me already and I was just too stupid to remember".